# Spring MVC: How do I get current url in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using [Thymeleaf Template Engine](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html) with Spring Web MVC and I am got stuck while creating url's with the help of current url. Is there any way to get current inside Thymeleaf HTML file? eg: Suppose my current url in my browser address bar is:

`http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles`

and now I want to make a url like this `http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles/store/samsung`

or

`http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles?min_price=10&max_price=100`.

So I the code will look like this

```
<a th:with="currentUrl='http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles'" 
   th:href="@{__${currentUrl}__/__${store.name}__}">
    Click to More Result
</a>
```

Here I am using `currentUrl` variable with hardcoded url, So I want to some solution for the same. The hardcoded value will not work everytime because I have dynamic categories.

I tried the same with relative url but its not working for me.

```
<a th:href="@{/store/__${store.name}__}">Click to More</a>

//will produce: http://localhost:8080/project/web/store/samsung
//I want: http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles/store/samsung
```

Please have a look and let me know if am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do you need the full URL? Why not simply use the relative URL?

Comment: In my case `http://localhost:8080/project` is my base url and `/web/category/{categoryName}` is mapped by controller. I tried the relative but it doesn't seems to work, I am using this for relative urls `<a th:href="@{/store/__${store.name}__}>" Click to More</a>`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Oh I got the solution for this. I missed the `{#httpServletRequest.requestURI}` in the documentation.

Here is the solution which is working for me:

```
<a th:href="@{__${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}__/store/__${store.name}__}">Click to More</a>
//Will produce: http://localhost:8080/project/web/category/mobiles/store/samsung
```

Comment: `${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}` works just fine (Thymeleaf Spring4 2.1.5)

Comment: In my application, requestURI give me something like this: [/store/something] while requestURL give me something like this: [https://www.example.com/store/something]. I opt for requestURL since complete url is better for my use case.

Comment: For the future readers; [you can use `${#request.requestURI}` in Thymeleaf 3.0(Link)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects)

Comment: Note that `#httpServletRequest.requestURI` doesn't include query string or fragment.

Comment: Thymeleaf 3.1 removed `#httpServerRequest`

Answer (score 32):

You can get the current URL using two single `'` quotes. Example:

```
<a th:href="@{''(lang=de)}">Deutsch</a>
```

Note that this unfortulately does not include existing URL parameters.

Comment: I just now tried again and it works... : <a th:href="@{''}">Current Page</a>. What is your Thymeleaf version? I use 3.0.2.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  I'm using 3.0.3; your example renders this `<a href="">Current Page</a>`.

Comment: Nice solution. Works here with Spring 5.0.4, Spring Boot 2.0, Thymeleaf 3.0.9

Comment: Note that, while this works, it doesn't return a full url; it generates relative urls

Answer (score 10):

In Thymeleaf 3.1, the current URL can be obtained from the context object:

```html
<form th:action="${#ctx.springRequestContext.requestUri}">
```

Comment: Still valid with Spring-Boot 3.1.1

Comment: not valid anymore in with spring boot 3.1.5.
I don't understand why this feature is removed. Whould be great to explain this change. I assume the thymleaf team as a great reason to do so.

Comment: here is the explanation: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/886

Answer (score 3):

If the requested url is for example : http://localhost:8080/my-page

I could get this value: **/my-page** using this: **httpServletRequest.requestURI**

For example, if you have to load some resource , you can use:

```
<script th:src="@{|${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}/main.js|}"></script>
```

And renderized html will be:

```
<script src="/my-page/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf 3.1 removed `#httpServerRequest`

Answer (score 2):

As of Thymeleaf 3.1 there appears to be no way to access the current request by default.

You will need to add it manually to the context, for example:

```java
@ModelAttribute("currentUrl")
public String getCurrentUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getRequestURI();
}
```

```xml
<a th:href="@{__${currentUrl}__/__${store.name}__}">
    Click to More Result
</a>
```