# Thymeleaf How to check current URL?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i was familiar with JSTL before and thymeleaf is something new to me.
What i want is to check if the current URL is the index page (/index), if so then make visible a div.

Here is a JSTL equivalent example

```
<c:set var="url" value="${ pageContext.request.requestURI }" />
<c:if test="${url=='/example/WEB-INF/views/inbox.jsp'}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div th:if="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI == '/example/WEB-INF/views/inbox.jsp'}">
some content
</div>
```

Comment: Man, where did you find this? I do not see in documentation.

Comment: Look [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects) :)

Answer (score 0):

For index page:

```
<div th:if="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/'}">
```