# How to create relative url with paramenters pointing to current page with URL syntax in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I have a paginator fragment where `i` is my page number. I want to generate URL that will point to current url but will append additional parameter.

My markup:

```
<a th:text="${i+1}" th:href="@{(page=${i})}">1</a>
```

So beeing on page lest say `/app/mypage` i would expect for result of `/app/mypage?page=1` for `i=1`.
What i get is `/app/(page=${i})`

What is the name of pointer to current page? If i use eg. `th:href="thispage@{(page=${i})}`url generated will be `/app/thispage?page=1` so it works as expected, but how to point to current page insteed of `thispage` ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf)?

Comment: Yes, I get there right after posting this question ;/ that double quote hack should be documented somewhere ;/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC: How do I get current url in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf)