# How to get the url before a button press to redirect to original page? Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a spring web app using thymeleaf on the front end. I have a controller on my backend that adds an item to the database. This same functionality is present across pages so it can be called from multiple urls. When the method is done I would like it redirect to the original url view.

So for example in this method:

```
 @GetMapping(value={"/addBook/{id}")
 public String addBookToCart(@PathVariable (value="id") int bookId) {
    // database functionality
    return "redirect:/"
 }
```

It would always return the redirection to /. But I want to be able to return to the page from where the user pressed the button. Essentially I want the saving to database functionality to happen in the background, without the user necessarily noticing. Is there a way to accomplish that? I was wondering if maybe I should be using POST instead of GET, but this isn't tied to a form, just a url upon clicking a button. Also you still typically return some view in a PostMapping I thought, so I am not sure how that'll solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466130/spring-mvc-how-do-i-get-current-url-in-thymeleaf

Comment: It does not because the passed url is just /addBook/{id} ... I want the url before that one. Should I do that via post mapping instead?

Comment: ${#httpServletRequest.requestURI} will get you the url of your current page you are at.